# Limit to infinity with absolute value

Tags: calculus, limits

I am learning math all by myself, no school, no teacher, and I come across a problem that I do not understand:

$\lim _{x \to -\infty } \frac{  | x^{2} - x  | +2 x^{2} }{1 - 3x^{2}}$

From my understanding, $|x²-x|$ should be translated as $-(x² - x)$, as we are approaching negative infinity. That will result in $-\frac{1}{3}$.
The book solutions is  $-1$, and I can confirm the solution by graphing the function. If I translate as $(x²-x)$ I get the $-1$.

So, why is it not $-(x²-x)$?

Thanks.

Comment: "as we are approaching negative infinity"  $x$ is a approaching negative infinity.  But that doesn't mean $x^2 - x$ is approaching negative infinity. We need to figure out whether $x^2 - x$ can be determined to be positive or negative.  Which is it.  Is $x^2 -x$ positive, negative or impossible to tell?

Comment: We could, just to be different, replace $x$ with $-y$ (or $y = -x$) so that we have $\lim_{y\to +\infty} \frac {|(-y)^2 + y| + 2(-y)^2}{1-3(-y)^2}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac {|y^2 + y|+2y^2}{1-3y^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have to consider whether $x^2 - x \ge 0$ and  therefore $|x^2 - x|$ should be translated as $x^2 -x$.  Or if $x^2 -x < 0$ and $|x^2 -x|$ should be translated as $-(x^2 -x) =x-x^2$.

Which is is it?

If $x < 0$ then $x^2 > 0$. And $-x > 0$.  And so $x^2 - x = x^2 + (-x) > 0 + 0 = 0$.

So $|x^2 -x| > 0$.  And so $|x^2-x|$ should be translated as $(x^2 -x)$.

If that seems counter intuitive try a value.  Let $x = - 10$.  Then $x^2 - x = (-10)^2 -(-10) = 100 + 10 = 110> 0$.

Comment: So, the need to evaluate before "translate" was what I was missing. I think it is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to-\infty$, you have that $x^2\to\infty$.

Even easier, $x^2-x>0$ for all $x<0$.